# How to remove onload event from the dynamically generated iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, iframe

```
<div class="voc_container content-container">
<div class="voc_content">
    <h3 class="heading-small">Tell us what you think of this page</h3>
    <span class="voc_content_open">Take a short survey to give us your feedback</span>
    <span class="voc_content_close js-hidden">Close</span>
    <div class="voc_content_survey js-hidden">
    <script id="ss-embed-380173">
    (function (d, w) { 
    var s, ss;
    ss = d.createElement('script');
    ss.type = 'text/javascript'; 
    ss.async = true; 
    ss.src = ('https:' == d.location.protocol ? 'https://' : 'http://') + 
'www.xxxxxx.co.uk/s/r/embed.aspx?i=341674&c=380173';
};
    s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ss, 
s); })(document, window);</script></div>
</div>
</div>**strong text**
```

which generates the html as

```
<iframe id="ss-embed-frame-380173" 
src="https://www.xxxxxxx.co.uk/s/YEXFX/" frameborder="0" style="border: 
0px currentColor; border-image: none; width: 100%; height: 400px; padding-
bottom: 4px;" onload="window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('ss-embed-
frame-380173').offsetTop);">&lt;a 
href="https://www.xxxxxxx.co.uk/s/YEXFX/"&gt;Please take our 
survey&lt;/a&gt;</iframe>
```

I tried using createelement to remove the listner

```
  ss.removeEventListener("onload","window.scrollTo(0, 
  document.getElementById('ss-embed-frame-380173').offsetTop);");
 ss.onload=function(){}
```

to remove the onload event from the dynamically generated event, but its not removing.

Could anyone can help me in guiding how to remove the onload event from the dynamically generated iframe element ???

```
onload="window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('ss-embed-
frame-380173').offsetTop);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MutationObserver` to observe elements being appended to `document`, call `.removeAttribute("onload")` on the element if `id` or other selector is matched, `.disconnect()` the observer instance

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
const config = {
  childList: true,
  subtree: true
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
    mutation.addedNodes.forEach(function(node) {
      if (new RegExp("^ss-embed-frame").test(node.id)) {
        node.removeAttribute("onload");
        observer.disconnect();
        console.log(node.getAttribute("onload"), node.outerHTML);
      }
    })
  })
})

observer.observe(document.documentElement, config);
</script>
<script>
let iframe = `<iframe id="ss-embed-frame-380173" 
src="data:text/plain,abc" frameborder="0" style="border: 
0px currentColor; border-image: none; width: 100%; height: 400px; padding-
bottom: 4px;" onload="window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById('ss-embed-
frame-380173').offsetTop);">&lt;a 
href="https://www.xxxxxxx.co.uk/s/YEXFX/"&gt;Please take our 
survey&lt;/a&gt;</iframe>`;

onload = function() {
  document.body.innerHTML += iframe
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#ss-embed-frame-380173").removeAttr("onload");
</script>
```